# How to set value for textview of fragment received from another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, textview

I don't know how to set in the textview of second fragment when received the value from another fragment. The data I received in the second fragment is the **"value"** object of StringList but I don't now how to set the data for it.

StringList class:

```
public class StringList {

    public String authorName;
    public String headline;
    public String publishedTime;
    public String newsDetail;

}
```

MainActivity:

```
//only useful code pasted below for tranfering thre value from fragment to another fragment and i have implemented the TransferValue to the mainActivity

        public void sendValue(StringList value, int positionValue) {

            FragmentTransaction transaction = frag.beginTransaction();
            BusinessDetail businessDetail = new BusinessDetail();
            businessDetail.receiveValue(value, positionValue);
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, businessDetail);
            transaction.commit();

        }
```

Fragment1:

```
    public class Business extends Fragment  {

        public List<StringList> businessNews = new ArrayList<>();

        TransferValue SendData;//here

        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
         public Business() {

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_business, container, false);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.business_recycler_view);

            FetchLists f = new FetchLists();
            f.execute(10, 0);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
    //here
            try {
                SendData = (TransferValue) context;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                Log.d("ashu", "implement the methods");
                throw new ClassCastException("implemented the methods");
            }
        }

//here
        public interface TransferValue {

            public void sendValue(StringList value, int positionValue);

        }

        public class FetchLists extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, List<StringList>> {

            @Override
            protected List<StringList> doInBackground(Integer... params) {

                int count = params[0];
                int offset = params[1];
    //api key changed
                String urlString = "https://newspi.og/v1/article?source=bloomerg&sortBy=tp&apiKey=5fdfd54f4aba5a5fdfvdf476ff528a8";
                urlString = urlString + "&count=" + count + "&offset=" + offset;

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                    String line = reader.readLine();
                    String response = "";
                    while (line != null) {
                        response += line;
                        line = reader.readLine();
                    }

                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray emailLists = object.getJSONArray("articles");

                    for (int i = 0; i < emailLists.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject listData = (JSONObject) emailLists.get(i);

                        StringList stringList = new StringList();
                        stringList.authorName = listData.getString("author");
                        stringList.headline = listData.getString("title");
                        stringList.publishedTime = listData.getString("publishedAt");
                        stringList.newsDetail = listData.getString("description");

                        businessNews.add(stringList);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return businessNews;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<StringList> result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                BusinessAdapter adapter = new BusinessAdapter(Business.this, result);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }

        public class BusinessAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BusinessHolder> {

            int prevposition = 0;
            private List<StringList> c;

            public BusinessAdapter(Business context, List<StringList> result) {
                c = context.businessNews;

            }

            @Override
            public BusinessHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                Context context = parent.getContext();
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_news, parent, false);

                return new BusinessHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(BusinessHolder holder, int position) {

                StringList m = c.get(position);
                holder.bindListName(m, position);

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return c.size();
            }
        }

        public class BusinessHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public TextView headlineTextview;
            public TextView authorTextview;
            public TextView timeTextview;

            public BusinessHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                headlineTextview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_headline);
                authorTextview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_author);
                timeTextview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_time);

            }

            public void bindListName(final StringList stringList, final int position) {

                headlineTextview.setText(stringList.headline);
                authorTextview.setText(stringList.authorName);
                timeTextview.setText(stringList.publishedTime);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                         BusinessDetail s = new BusinessDetail();
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, s);
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                    } });}}}}
```

Fragment 2:

```
public class BusinessDetail extends Fragment {

    Bundle bundle;
    private TextView headlineSecond;
    private TextView authorSecond;
    private TextView detailsSecond;
    private List<StringList> s;

    public BusinessDetail() {
    }

    public void receiveValue(StringList value, int positionValue) {

        bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("news", value.authorName);
      }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_business_detail, container, false);

        headlineSecond = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_headline_second);
        authorSecond = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_author_second);
        detailsSecond = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_details_second);

// I want to set the values received to the textview here

        return view;}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send arraylist of any custom class data using **Parcelable** from one activity/fragment to next activity/fragment.

In previous fragment add data in bundle using putParcelableArrayList method. for e.g.

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("KEY_NAME",arrayName);
```

In next frgament get that data in onCreate using getParcelableArrayList method.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        ArrayList<Item> itemArray = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("KEY_NAME");
    }
}
```

And main thing is that change your StringList class to Parcelable. For Parcelable class example click below link..

[Parcelable Class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

Comment: thank you! but i don't want to do like that as i start again by changing some code......plz give an answer by the above condition. Thanx again!

Comment: @avadra_kedra For above condition, parcelable is perfect for list of data of pojo (custom class). And for single Object attach that all values individual and get that in another fragment. I hope this will help u..

Answer (score 2):

**Please consider using `newInstance` pattern for passing values to fragment as calling `receiveValue` method after instantiating fragment is not a good practice.**  You should define your object as `Parcelable` and pass it to new fragment via `newInstance` method.

However if you received values via invocation of method `receiveValue` there is no need to use a `Bundle`. `Bundle` is used when you want to pass values from `Fragment` or `Activity` to another `Fragment`. For saving values you can define **Global** Variables like you did with `TextView`s. For Example:

```
Bundle bundle;
StringList mStringList;
private TextView headlineSecond;
private TextView authorSecond;
private TextView detailsSecond;
private List<StringList> s;

public BusinessDetail() {
}

public void receiveValue(StringList value, int positionValue) {
    mStringList = value;
}
```

P.S: But for future reference, you can retrieve **String** value from `Bundle` by calling `getString(String key)`. In your case it would be like:

```
String value = bundle.getString("news");
yourTextView.setText(value);
```

Also remove these lines, they don't do anything in your current fragment unless you trying to start a new `Fragment`:

```
BusinessDetail detail = new BusinessDetail();
detail.setArguments(bundle);
```

For detailed explanation of fragment's communication with example and code snippet you can visit here:
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html

Comment: Yes! of Course i have passed the value from  fragment to other fragment in which i am getting in the value object...but how do i set this value to the textview fields? thanks for your consideration

Comment: I don't see any code related to passing value or initiating of fragment. I update my answer to include more detail on this matter.

Comment: i am getting a null pointer exception in the "String value = bundle.getString("news");" ?

Comment: If you have set bundle with setArguments from caller then you have to get bundle through getArguments.. If not I must see how you passed values to current fragment.

Comment: yes i have done the same thing using setArguments and the getArguments.....by the way i have edited my code check it out

Comment: you can simply use bundle to transfer the value from fragment to fragment     https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Define a global variable as I mentioned will do the trick but Please use a method defined in http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html or https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html as what your are doing right now is not a good practice.